# Is it possible to write a dset function for Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm working on an excel project that would benefit from a dset function or visual basic script.  What I envision is a function that is similar to excel's [dget](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dget.php) database function but instead of getting data from a database/table that meets the criteria it will set/insert data into a table at the intersection that meets the criteria.   I have a rather large data set so the function needs to be efficient.

My table will have have a structure similar to this:[image]

I'd like to have the ability to do something like:

```
dset(NetSales,Actual,FY10,Jan,Jan_Fcst_Amt,1000)
```

where 1000 is the value that I'm setting.

My goal is to have the ability to extract a forecast scenario, input it into a table that then serves as the data source for a pivot table.

Has anyone ever done anything like this.  What's the best approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible approach :

Create a hidden column which concatenates the columns which serve to select the row (not forgetting a field separator), e.g. `=A2 & "|" & B2 & "|" & C2 & "|" & D2`

In a VBA function use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match()` to find the offset of the concatenation of the row search fields in the composite column.

Then use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match()` to find the offset of the column search field.

The you can use `ActiveSheet.Cells(x,y).Formula=z` to set the cell you require.

This approach maximizes the use of Excel's builtin functions which should be faster than anything you can write in VBA.

Comment: A very interesting approach. I'll give this a try and see how it works. Thanks!